# Comparing to List in vb.net and adding data into Final List

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on VB.NET. I am stuck with a problem where I have two lists.
The lists have different object types; however, both lists contain one common property. Here is the example i can give about those list.

1)  Driver List

```
ID     DriverName    DriverCity
1          A         Chicago
2          B         San Jose
3          C         New York
```

2) Trailer List

```
ID       TrailerName
1            A
2            B
3            C
4            D
5            E
6            F
```

Now I need a new list which contains all the trailer IDS with a Driver (example A).  I want to compare both list and add the missing items into the final list.

Comment: Are you matching based on the value in ID?? If you are populating the lists from a database then a new query might be the way to go, rather than iterating through the lists.

Comment: I don't see anything in your data to relate a Trailer to the driver, unless the trailer is named after the driver... and if that's true, that's poor database design. You should be looking somewhere for an intersection table that maps The Trailer ID to the Driver ID, add a DriverID field to the Trailer table, or (less likely based on the names) add a TrailerID to the Driver table.

Comment: I really don't know what you could possibly mean by "missing items": both lists contain different object types so it stands to reason that each list would be "missing" all the items from the other…

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned that he's using a database at all .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot do that in your dbms because you are not using a database at all. Also assuming that the `ID` property is the *common property* and you simply want to find all trailers without a driver (according to the ID).

You can use `Enumerable.Except` to find the set difference and `Join` to get the original trailer object:

```
Dim trailerIDs = From t In trailers Select t.ID
Dim driverIDs = From d In drivers Select d.ID
Dim trailersWithoutDriverIDs = trailerIDs.Except(driverIDs)
Dim trailersWithoutDriver = From t In trailers 
                            Join id In trailersWithoutDriverIDs On t.ID Equals id
                            Select t
' now add missing drivers '
For Each trailer In trailersWithoutDriver 
    Dim driver = new Driver()
    driver.ID = trailer.ID
    driver.DriverName = trailer.TrailerName
    ' which city?? '
    drivers.Add(driver)
Next trailer
```